# How to copy multiple files using fs.copyFile node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am using `fs.copyFile` to copy files from one location to another. I am doing this *twice* in order to copy two files. It's redundant and I would like to make my code better by maybe copying both files to the destination with a single call? How can I achieve this?

```
fs.copyFile('src/blah.txt', 'build/blah.txt', (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
});
fs.copyFile('src/unk.txt', 'build/unk.txt', (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply create a function of your own that takes the src and dest path and an array of filenames as arguments:

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const copyFilePromise = util.promisify(fs.copyFile);

function copyFiles(srcDir, destDir, files) {
    return Promise.all(files.map(f => {
       return copyFilePromise(path.join(srcDir, f), path.join(destDir, f));
    }));
}

// usage
copyFiles('src', 'build', ['unk.txt', 'blah.txt']).then(() => {
   console.log("done");
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Could I use `async` `await` here instead of promisify and Promise.all ?

Comment: @AngelaRoux - You could, but the idea behind this design was to let all the copy operations run in parallel (for potentially faster end to end execution time) and you would generally need to use `Promise.all()` to track when a bunch of parallel operations are done.  You could serialize them one after another using `async/await` or you could use `await copyFiles(...)` instead of `copyFiles().then(...)`.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best option is to use [***fs-extra***](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra):

```
const fse = require('fs-extra');

const srcDir = `path/to/file`;
const destDir = `path/to/destination/directory`;

// To copy a folder
fse.copySync(srcDir, destDir, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log("success!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const files = ['/files/a.js', '/files/b.js', '/files/c.txt'];
files.forEach(file => {
  fs.copyFile(path.join(__dirname + file), path.join(__dirname + '/files/backup/' + path.basename(file)), err => {
    if(!err){
    console.log(file + " has been copied!");
  }
  })

});
```

Use the following code if forced replace is unwanted.

```
    const fs = require('fs');
        const path = require('path');
        const files = ['/files/a.js','/files/b.js','/files/c.txt'];   
          files.forEach(file => {
    let basename = path.basename(file);
    let oldFile = path.join(__dirname+file);
    let newFile = path.join(__dirname+'/files/backup/'+basename);
    if (!fs.existsSync(newFile)) {
      fs.copyFile(oldFile, newFile, err=>{
        if(!err){
          console.log(basename+" has been copied!");
        }
      });
    }else{
      console.log(basename+" already existed!");
    }
  });
```

Comment: I think we should not be using async functions inside forEach which is synchronous. Can u check once. Because, sir tracking might get a little problematic in the case

Comment: @klvenky Thanks, It was expected fs.copyFile

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented the function above with the walk npm package to get all the files.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/walk

This gets all files within sub folders as well.

Worked copying 16,000 images from my Go Pro into one single folder on my desktop.

```
const util = require('util');

const fs = require('fs');

const path = require('path');

const copyFilePromise = util.promisify(fs.copyFile);

const walk = require('walk');

let files = [];

let source_folder = '/Volumes/Untitled/DCIM';

let destination_folder = '/Users/dave/Desktop/pics';

let walker = walk.walk(source_folder, {
    followLinks: false
});

walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {

    let file_path = root + '/' + stat.name;

    files.push({
        src: file_path,
        des: destination_folder + '/' + stat.name
    });

    next();

});

walker.on('end', function() {

    copyFiles(files).then(() => {

        console.log("done");

    }).catch(err => {

        console.log(err);

    });

});

function copyFiles(files) {
    return Promise.all(files.map(f => {
        return copyFilePromise(f.src, f.des);
    }));
}
```